# OnClickListener does not work on any platform

Tags: java, android

The activity builds a table dinamically. I would like to add an OnClickListener to all rows.
I am doing like this:

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.body);
for (final Document d : result) {
    TableRow row;
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(
                LastDocumentsActivity.this).inflate(
                R.layout.last_documents_body_row_portrait, null);

        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.date)).setText(d
                .getDate());
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.number)).setText(d
                .getNumber());
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.value_netto)).setText(d
                .getValueNetto().toString());
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.currency)).setText(d
                .getCurrency());

        table.addView(row);
    } else {
        row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(
                LastDocumentsActivity.this).inflate(
                R.layout.last_documents_body_row_landscape, null);

        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.number)).setText(d
                .getNumber());
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.date)).setText(d
                .getDate());
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.value_netto)).setText(d
                .getValueNetto().toString());
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.value_brutto)).setText(d
                .getValueBrutto().toString());
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.currency)).setText(d
                .getCurrency());
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.status)).setText(d
                .getStatus());
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.responsible_person))
                .setText(d.getPersonResponsible());
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.orderId)).setText(Integer
                .toString(d.getId()));

        table.addView(row);
    }
    row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("info", "OnClickListener works.");
            Intent i = new Intent(LastDocumentsActivity.this,
                    DocumentDetailsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("document_id", d.id);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

It works perfectly in the Emulator (3,2" QVGA (ADP2) (320x480:mdpi) Android 2.2), but doesn't on my phone. (Huawei Ascend Y300, Android 4.1.1)
The screen looks like the same (apart from resolution), just the OnClickListener does not work. What could be the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried on other emulators?

Comment: Where are you initializing the row??

Comment: @Manishika I edited my question and copied the whole code.

Comment: @AndrewSchuster Now I've tried 4.0" WVGA (480x80:hdpi) Android 4.1.2 too, it doesn't not work either. So probably the problem related to the Android API.